# Github pull request diff

Tags: github, pull-request

Naive question for github pull request api.
I found from Github API documentation ProTip that pullrequest.diff gives unified diff.

However, going through the documentation for [Pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) as well as for [Pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination), I cannot clearly figure out if for large diff in a pull request, is the response paginated?

I hope its not an overlook on my part, but if anybody can point me to that info, it would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to `https://github.com/org/repo/pull/123.diff` to get the diff for PR 123.

The unified diff format has no concept of pagination.

Emperical testing says no, it is not paginated.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I was referring to. Thank you for your response